# Where to Store Confidential Data in Mac

Tags: c#, macos, mono, registry

I had used the registry to store confidential information in Windows.The application used to load and check info from the registry.Now im in the process of porting the application(coded in c#) for mac using Mono.

Where do you recommend to store the data?

Comment: In a database, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in `KeyChain`.

> In Mac OS X, keychain files are stored in ~/Library/Keychains/,
>   /Library/Keychains/, and /Network/Library/Keychains/, and the Keychain
>   Access GUI application is located in the Utilities folder in the
>   Applications folder. It is free, open source software released under
>   the terms of the APSL. The command line equivalent of Keychain Access
>   is /usr/bin/security. The keychain file(s) stores a variety of data
>   fields including a title, URL, notes and password. Only the passwords
>   and Secure Notes are encrypted, with Triple DES.
>
> The default keychain file is the login keychain, typically unlocked on
>   login by the user's login password, although the password for this
>   keychain can instead be different from a user’s login password, adding
>   security at the expense of some convenience.[5] The Keychain Access
>   application does not permit setting an empty password on a keychain.
>   The keychain may be set to be automatically "locked" if the computer
>   has been idle for a time,[6] and can be locked manually from the
>   Keychain Access application. When locked, the password has to be
>   re-entered next time the keychain is accessed, to unlock it.
>   Overwriting the file in ~/Library/Keychains/ with a new one (e.g. as
>   part of a restore operation) also causes the keychain to lock and a
>   password is required at next access.
>
> Keychain Access is a Mac OS X application that allows the user to
>   access the Keychain and configure its contents, including passwords
>   for websites, web forms, FTP servers, SSH accounts, network shares,
>   wireless networks, groupware applications, encrypted disk images, etc.
>   It unlocks, locks, and displays passwords saved by the system which
>   are dynamically linked to the user's login password, as well as
>   managing root certificates, keys, and secure notes. Its graphical user
>   interface displays various keychains, with there usually being at
>   least two; the login keychain and the system keychain. It also
>   includes the Keychain first aid utility that can repair problems with
>   Keychains. Various events can cause problems with Keychains, and
>   sometimes the only solution to solving a problem is to delete the
>   Keychain, which also deletes any passwords stored in the Keychain, and
>   create a new one. It is usually found in the Utilities folder in under
>   Applications in OS X. As an ancillary application to OS X, it is
>   subject to updates via Software Update and thus should not be moved
>   out of the Utilities folder. There is also an included command-line
>   tool to access the keychain, called "security".

Extract from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_%28Apple%29).

**Note: With root password, you can view nearly every saved password on the computer.**

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer

Comment: If the password is encrypted,then ?

Comment: @techno: encrypted and saved in keychain?

Comment: @techno: no problem you save it in that way too.